# How to speed up Netbeans 8.1 local synchronization

Tags: php, netbeans, synchronization, netbeans-8

I have  "special" win 2008R2 server that cannot have FTP, SFTP, ssh or WebDAV installed. I'm trying to use netbeans local sync of php files to a share..

Netbeans 8.1 is painfully slow syncing files. I have about 500 files. It has been running for over 4 hrs.. and still not finished.

Any suggestions on how to speed this up ?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean move them locally ?

Comment: The files you're trying to sync

Comment: yeah,, that won't work  but I setup a remote mirror and force the push with a script when I hit run..  Not he best, but it works fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans does not have a fix for the slow synchronization issue. Other work arounds are required which may include FTP and volume/directory mirroring.